# If a polynomial ideal can be generated by $k$ elements, can it be generated by $k$ elements of any generating set?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I = (p_1,\ldots, p_k) \subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

If we have a set of $k'$ polynomials such that $(q_1,\ldots,q_{k'}) = I$, can we always find a $k$-member subset such that $(q_{\sigma_1},\ldots,q_{\sigma_k}) = I$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? You may begin with $n=k=1$.

Comment: It's also worth asking the same question about the most basic of rings, $\mathbb Z$.  You'll see a way, perhaps, to move that answer to the polynomial ring.

Comment: My hunch was that the answer is yes, but now I see your point, Landscape.  Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, to reply someone's comment in your post, you should @someone to remind him/her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1) = (X-2,X-1) \ne (X-2)$ and $\ne(X-3)$.

Comment: You know the funny thing about this?  Many times have I used precisely this type of calculation (i.e. $(p_1,\ldots,p_k) = (1)$) to show that there are no solutions to $p_1 = \ldots = p_k = 0$.  For some reason, when I considered the question above, I just drew a blank...